# Change height of an expansion tile in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have this expansion tile which takes too much padding which results in a lot of wasted space, how can I get down the top and bottom padding of this expansion tile?

```
  Widget additiveCard(
  BuildContext context, List<FoodAdditive> additives, Product product, bool good) {
  String subtitleText = good ? "השפעה נמוכה" : "השפעה גבוהה";

  return Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    child: ExpansionTile(
      tilePadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      onExpansionChanged: (bool expanding) {
        setState(() => isExpanded = expanding);
        isExpanded ? _controller.forward() : _controller.reverse();
      },
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              title: Text(
                getTitle("תוספים"),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              leading: Icon(Icons.science),
              subtitle: Text(subtitleText),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              buildRatingCircle(16, good ? Colors.green : Colors.red),

            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      children: [
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: product
                      .countAdditivesByRating(additives)
                      .entries
                      .where((entry) => entry.value > 0)
                      .map((entry) {
                    int rating = entry.key;
                    int ratingCount = entry.value;
                    return buildAdditiveCircle(16, ratingCount, rating);
                  })
                      .toList()
                      .reversed
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

I just want to adjust the height of it when it's collapsed not when it's open.

I tried wrapping it with a container of a fixed height but that's just taking all the space it needs in advance and implies it to the whole expansiontile and not just the first row with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this block

```
listTileTheme: ListTileTheme.of(context).copyWith(
//               dense: true,
              minVerticalPadding: isExpanded ? null : 20,
            ),
```

in the wrapping Theme class

Adding that allows you to control the theme of ListTile which is basically what Expansion ListTile is made of.

So you would have

```
  Widget additiveCard(
  BuildContext context, List<FoodAdditive> additives, Product product, bool good) {
  String subtitleText = good ? "השפעה נמוכה" : "השפעה גבוהה";

  return Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
      listTileTheme: ListTileTheme.of(context).copyWith(
//               dense: true,
              minVerticalPadding: isExpanded ? null : 20,
       ),
    ),
    child: ExpansionTile(
      tilePadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      onExpansionChanged: (bool expanding) {
        setState(() => isExpanded = expanding);
        isExpanded ? _controller.forward() : _controller.reverse();
      },
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              title: Text(
                getTitle("תוספים"),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              leading: Icon(Icons.science),
              subtitle: Text(subtitleText),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              buildRatingCircle(16, good ? Colors.green : Colors.red),

            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      children: [
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: product
                      .countAdditivesByRating(additives)
                      .entries
                      .where((entry) => entry.value > 0)
                      .map((entry) {
                    int rating = entry.key;
                    int ratingCount = entry.value;
                    return buildAdditiveCircle(16, ratingCount, rating);
                  })
                      .toList()
                      .reversed
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

It gives a flicker behaviour when switching between collapsed and expanded view, but I think you can modify the minVerticalPadding's value to get the best possible outcome.

Comment: It's strange that flutter doesnt provide an out of the box solution for this but thanks anyway I'll put it to 0 and get with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of ExapnsionTile for example:-  height 200 with Container.

```
             Padding(
                paading:EdgeEnsets.all(10)
                child: Container(
                  height: 200, // Set the desired height
                  child: ExpansionTile())
              ),
```

Comment: But when I set the height for ExpansionTile it will set the same height for the expanded content which I don't want, I want to control the height only when it's closed.